# Is it possible for the viewers to get rid of the 60FPS fast forward effect?

Tags: video, framerate, filming

Since I and Everyone else watched too many 24/30FPS throught our lives, whenever We see 60FPS or faster motion picture we feel like its fast forwarded thus makes it terribly unnatural.

I want to shoot some 60FPS movies but I am afraid of the audience unconciously disliking my movies (due to the movies feel anormal) so the question is: In the future where 60FPS (hopefully) gets more and more into the Youtube videos, will the current generation and future teenagers get used to the 60FPS video and thus the movies wont feel fast forwarded and anormal ?

In Short:Is it possible to get used to the 60FPS video so it wont feel fast forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 fps does not look like "fast forward". It simply looks natural. It breaks the old-school film look, so people start paying more attention to what is happening on the screen, including acting and dialogs. A crappy movie, barely watchable in 24p, falls apart when interpolated to 60p or 120p by modern TV sets. Just shoot better movies ;)

By the way, for quite a long time in the U.K. they used movie cameras for shooting outside on location, and TV cameras for shooting inside on the set, so for the British "film look" used to mean outside, "smooth look" used to mean inside.

Comment: Worth noting that TV was always effectively 50 fps (in Britain / PAL countries, 60 in US), because it was interlaced. So you had two fields per frame, where a field was half the resolution of the frame. Hence the smoothness of TV.

Comment: @stib This does not really matter, because movies are telecined for TV, so their temporal feel is preserved. Well, mostly preserved, because in Europe it is 4% faster, while in the U.S. movies exhibit characteristic judder caused by 2:3 pulldown. The "soap opera" effect seen on many modern TV sets is caused by the set interpolating missing frames, not simply repeating them as in the usual telecine process.

Comment: @RustyCore why don't they use the "traditional" telecine process? What is the time requirement difference?

Comment: @JonathanIrons The "soap opera" effect can be turned off on most (all?) of the TVs that have this option. I guess, we are moving to faster fps, leaving 24fps behind. Also, they say that 24fps is too jerky for 3D.

Comment: True for movies, and almost all footage shot these days. Only really applies to footage that was shot on video.